# Remove a specific word from a file using shell script

Tags: sed

I would request some help with a basic shell script that should do the following job.

1. File a particular word from a given file (file path is always constant)
2. Backup the file
3. Delete the specific word or replace the word with ;
4. Save the file changes

Example

- File Name - abc.cfg
- Contains the following lines

`network;private;Temp;Windows;System32`

I've used the following SED command for the operation

`sed -i -e "/Temp;/d" abc.cfg`

The output is not as expected. The complete line is removed instead of just the word **Temp;**

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

sed matches against lines, and `/d` is the delete directive, which is why you get a deleted line. Instead, use substitution to replace the offending word with nothing:

```
sed 's/Temp;//g' abc.cfg
```

The `/g` modifier means "globlal", in case the offending word appears more than once. I would hold off on the `-i` (inline) flag until you are sure of your command, in general, or use `-i .backup`.

Comment: on a mac: sed -i '' 's/Temp;//g' abc.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I used your suggestion but couldn't get through. I appreciate the input though.

I was able to achieve this using the following SED syntax

sed -e "s/Temp//g" -i.backup abc.cfg

I wanted to take the backup before the change & hence -i was helpful.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment. I did not receive a notification for it, and only by chance saw this. Please delete this answer, and comment on my answer if you need clarification. If my answer did solve you problem, no need to comment, please hit the V tick next to the up/down vote, so future readers know this question is solved. You may want to have another look at the [tour] to better understand this site, which is very different from normal forums.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that should solve your issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the file name from the user
echo "Enter the file name:"
read filename

# Backup the file
cp "$filename" "$filename.bak"

# Delete the word "Temp" from the file
sed -i -e "s/Temp;/;/g" "$filename"

# Save the file changes
echo "File saved successfully!"
```